# SoftLayer API: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 'https:/api.softlayer.com/soap/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package?xsd'

Tags: php, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm using the SoftLayer PHP library to make SoftLayer API call to from a shell script.

I got the following error when invoking

```
SoftLayer_SoapClient::getClient ( "SoftLayer_Product_Package", $pakagekey, $userName, $apiKey );
```

> There was an error querying the SoftLayer API: Could not connect to
>   host ERROR       |  | SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema
>   from 'https://api.softlayer.com/soap/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package?xsd'
>   ERROR       | PHP | ERR 1 with message SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema:
>   can't import schema from
>   'https://api.softlayer.com/soap/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package?xsd' in
>   /softlayer/SoftLayer/SoapClient.class.php:262

The SoapClient.class.php 262 has

```
$soapClient = new SoftLayer_SoapClient($endpointUrl . $serviceName . '?wsdl');
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine for me. Please check that you can open successful in a browser these links:

https://api.softlayer.com/soap/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package?wsdl
https://api.softlayer.com/soap/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package?xsd

The error looks like your machine is not able to connect to those links.

Also make sure you are using the last version of the PHP API client

Regards

Comment: I also see the following error:   SoapClient::SoapClient(): Failed to enable crypto' in /SoftLayer/SoapClient.class.php:262.    Any idea if there's any dependency php module I need to install on my machine  ?     My product currently uses the SoftLayer php client downloaded from June 2015. The latest SoftLayer client from Oct. 2015 uses different file structure. It said it is not backward compatible.  I need to stay with the June 2015 Soap client for a while.

Comment: I tested using the old version and it worked as well. Regarding the requirements you need to use PHP 5.2.3 or supirior and install the extentions for SOAP or XML-RCP see more information here http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/PHP